# Can't Query Single CloudKit Record by recordName UUID

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit

I have a `CloudKit` app where records are stored locally in `CoreData`. When creating the `CoreData` record, a `UUID` is generated and populated to the system recordName field. The app creates and saves records in `CoreData` then uploads the records to `CloudKit`. This works fine.

However, I am now coding to modify a record and am not able to fetch a record by the recordName UUID. I have not been successful setting a predicate to search for only that record. I can retrieve all records with `TRUEPREDICATE` and I can also retrieve a single record from a field I created in the `CloudKit` record type. I created a field called myRecordName where I store the same UUID as the `CloudKit` recordName. A query using the myRecordName works fine.

I have shown three methods below for the predicates. If p1 and p2 are not both commented out the app crashes on running. I assume I am missing something really simple here. Any guidance would be appreciated. Xcode 10.2.1, iOS 12.2, testing on a real device.

If either p1 or p2 or both are not commented out, the console shows:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CKReference rangeOfString:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x280878520'

```
func queryDatabase() {

    let recordZone = CKRecordZone(zoneName: "PrimaryZone")
    let recName = "0E763775-5AD3-4A50-BFB8-AC310180E8A2"

    let recID = CKRecord.ID(recordName: recName, zoneID: recordZone.zoneID)
    let searchRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "Patient", recordID: recID)

    let p1 = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", CKRecord.Reference(recordID: recID, action: CKRecord_Reference_Action.none))
    let p2 = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", CKRecord.Reference(record: searchRecord, action: CKRecord_Reference_Action.none))

    //let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE")
    let p3 = NSPredicate(format: "myRecordName = %@", recName)

    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Patient", predicate: p3)
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "lastNameText", ascending: true)
    query.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    privateDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: recordZone.zoneID) { (results, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("error querying database\(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
        } else {

            DVC.ckRecords = results!
            //print(results!)
            print(DVC.ckRecords.first!)

        }//if error else
    }//perform query block

}//queryDatabase
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never used CloudKit, so maybe I'm wrong, but…

The two problem lines of code, `p1=` and `p2=`, attempt to create a `NSPredicate` using a format string.  Each format string contains **two** *var arg substitutions*, aka *placeholders*: `%K` and `%@`.  So for this to work, that format string argument must be followed by **two** more arguments: first a key path, which should be a string (%K), and second a object for its value (%@).  For your purposes here, the key path is probably just an attribute name.

But you have only provided one more argument, a `CKRecord.Reference` object, which the system tries to parse for the first (attribute name, string) argument.  The error you are getting is typical of what happens when the system tries to parse an object such as `CKRecord.Reference` when it was expecting a string.  Swift may be quite type safe but old-fashioned NSPredicate var args functions are not :)

To fix this problem (and move on to the next one), you should provide the key path (argument name) argument, something like this:

```
let p1 = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", "recordID", CKRecord.Reference(recordID: recID, action: CKRecord_Reference_Action.none))
let p2 = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", "recordID", CKRecord.Reference(record: searchRecord, action: CKRecord_Reference_Action.none))
```

Since I don't understand exactly what you are doing, you may need to tweak those two lines a bit.  But the point is that, given your format string, you need three arguments to `NSPredicate(format:)`, and the middle one needs to be a string representing a key path or attribute name.

Comment: I see your point. I have tried several versions of the suggestions and the app doesn't crash at run, but now I get "error querying databaseOptional("Invalid predicate: recordKey (0E763775-5AD3-4A50-BFB8-AC310180E8A2) contains invalid characters")". That certainly ought to mean something to me but I still don't get it. There must be something about the CloudKit Reference type that prevents me from doing this. For now I'll use my own defined myRecordName which is always the same UUID as the recordName. Kludgy, but it seems to work.

Comment: That latest error indicates that maybe you are passing something that contains parentheses as the argument immediately following the format string *%K == %@*.  That is indeed an error.  This argument is supposed to be a key path, which must be a valid Objective-C symbol name (with maybe some dots).  Therefore it cannot include a parentheses character.

Comment: No parentheses. It is, however, a string - recName above, which of course must have quotes.

Comment: @user2698617 Hi, did you find a solution? I'd love to refactor away my extra UUID field and query by recordName instead